# Can I do this to not waste a variable

Tags: python, io

Instead of

```
list = []
item = input()
list.append(item)
```

Can I just straight up do:

```
list.append(input())
```

Just not wasting the item variable
Actually Codeium popped up saying this so just checking facts

Can it work? Detailed explanation

Comment: Sorry, forget to add list = [] add the second ex

Comment: `list.append(input())` would not work as list has not been defined yet; (Aside from the builtin obj). However `my_item = [input()]` does work as does `my_item = []` followed by `my_item.append(input())`

Comment: Is someone charging you for variables? They are free — you can't waste them. You should use as few or as many as you need to make your code readable and maintainable. A more important consideration is structuring your code so the scope of variables is contained in functions and modules so they are easy to isolate and understand.

Comment: This is not an answer, but I strongly advise you **not to use python keywords** like `list`.
It will overwrite built-in function `list`, which could mess up the execution of program afterwards. Instead, you could use variable names such as `arr` or `lst`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes it will work.
2. The `append` method requires a value.  The `input()` call supplies the value.  (If you need *more* detail, you will need to clarify what you need to be explained.)
3. The "waste" of a variable is negligible ... unless you are doing this in a recursive method AND the recursion is many calls deep.

   However, the code is (arguably) easier to read if you don't use an unnecessary temporary variable there.